# Group by month name in sql using SqlKata

Tags: c#, sql, group-by, query-builder, sqlkata

I have the following query, and I want to group the result by the *month* instead of the full date. 
Is there any easy way to achieve that ? noting that I am using the SqlKata library

Expected Result

```
Month | Balance
------|--------
1     | 100
2     | 150
3     | 300
```

Instead of

```
Date       | Balance
--------   |------
2018-01-01 | 100
2018-01-02 | 90
.....      | ....
2018-02-01 | 150
```

My current code is:

```
var balances = db.Query("Balances")
    .WhereBetween("Date", from, to)
    .Select("Date")
    .Select("sum([Balance]) as Balance")
    .GroupBy("Date")
    .Get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [GroupByRaw](https://sqlkata.com/docs/group#groupbyraw) ( and `SelectRaw` ) Just use a database built in functions to get the month. Let's supose you are working with SQL Server and [MONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

```
var balances = db.Query("Balances")
    .WhereBetween("Date", from, to)
    .SelectRaw("MONTH(Date)")
    .Select("sum([Balance]) as Balance")
    .GroupByRaw("MONTH(Date)")
    .Get();
```

Disclaimer: check your database brand docs for date functions to know how to get month from date in your case.

Answer (score -1):

Just do this:

`` select month(`Date`); ``